# How to pass a variable value to a Controller in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to pass multiple values into a query and execute it. How can I do?
Eg:
`values = name.to_s + 'Check'`
`data = TestController::values.method_name`
Outcome: `TestController::RailsCheck`

How I can get multiple values in values variable?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do but there are many different way to do it, either you can create Hashes and use it, or as in your code seem you want to make object and than call its method name. So I am giving you here sample class and with object example you can add it in either concern if you are using it with ActiveRecord or you can add in lib folder if you are using in controllers.

```
class Solution
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def method_name
    name.to_s + 'Check'
  end
end

values = Solution.new('Rails')
puts values.method_name
```